# Not Able to connect to Oracle Autonomous Datawarehouse Cloud using any of the way

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, data-warehouse, ioerror, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, sqlcl

I am trying to connect to the Oracle Autonoumous Datawarehouse using JDBC Thin connections and wallet using below ways:
1. SQLDeveloper
2. Sqlcl

I am following the steps mentioned in https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-5ED3C08C-1A84-4E5A-B07A-A5114951AA9E.

I have downloaded the wallet file and modified the sqlnet.ora file and set the directory pointing to the location of wallet file also TNS_NAME variable is also set and pointing to the right directory.

I am getting "Error Message = IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms." in both the ways, by sql developer and Sqlcl.

Also there is no proxy configured in the network. So proxy configurations are not added to the configuration file.

Comment: you're reading the wrong docs, see my links below

Comment: Did you try connecting using Plain Java? Follow these instructions (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/documentation/atp-5073445.html) to connect using plain Java.

Answer (score 2):

Use the special connection type we setup for you, Cloud PDB.

[image]

In SQLcl, simply run

> set cloudconfig c:path/to/wallet.zip

Then

> show tns

To get a list of the services you can connect to.

[Docs for Connecting with SQL Developer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-sql-dev182.html#GUID-14217939-3E8F-4782-BFF2-021199A908FD)

[Docs for Connecting with SQLcl](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-sqlcl.html#GUID-AC24404D-8D0B-4716-83F6-F0F501318011)

As you can see in the screenshot, for version 18.3, the connection type has been renamed to 'Cloud Wallet' and we added support for defining a HTTP Proxy for connections.

This connection type is designed for both Autonomous Data Warehouse and Autonomous Transaction Processing Oracle Cloud Services (ATP and ADW).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply.
I tried to connect through v18.3 and used the Cloud Wallet connection type but facing the same issue mentioned above. Below is the error message we are getting.

**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, Authentication lapse 0 ms.**

Is there any special configuration required in the client to connect to the Oracle cloud?
We are using the client provided VPN and there is no proxy being used in our VPN.

Please have a look at the screenshot attached for more details.

[image]

Comment: >>"Is there any special configuration required in the client to connect to the Oracle cloud?" No, not outside using the Cloud Wallet connection type